# Unable to build Newtonsoft.Json from source locally

Tags: json.net

I am attempting to build Newtonsoft.Json from source locally.
I downloaded the source as a zip file.
After installing a variety of prerequisites, I was able to get it to build in Visual Studio 2019. However, the DLL produced in that way is incomplete.
I noticed the Build folder with various scripts. However, when I execute runbuild, I get errors:

> C:\Users(redacted).nuget\packages\microsoft.build.tasks.git\1.0.0-beta2-18618-05\build\Microsoft.Build.Tasks.Git.targets(20,5):
>   warning : Unable to locate repository containing directory
>   'C:(redacted)\Newtonsoft.Json\Src\Newtonsoft.Json'.
>   [C:(redacted)\Newtonsoft.Json\Src\Newtonsoft.Json\Newtonsoft.Json.csproj]
>   C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual
>   Studio\2019\Enterprise\MSBuild\Current\Bin\Roslyn\Microsoft.Managed.Core.target
>   s(104,5): error : SourceRoot items must include at least one top-level
>   (not nested) item when DeterministicSourcePaths is true
>   [C:(redacted)\Newtonsoft.Json\Src\Newtonsoft.Json\Newtonsoft.Json.csproj]

Any tips appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Taking the error message at face value, I did some searches and came up with

> Only set DeterministicSourcePaths to true on a build/CI server, never for local builds.

at https://github.com/dotnet/sourcelink/blob/master/docs/README.md

So, I added

```
<DeterministicSourcePaths>false</DeterministicSourcePaths>
```

to Newtonsoft.Json.csproj

Result: errors are gone

Still not getting a strong name for the DLL. But, I'll save that for a fresh post since this one already got down-voted...!?

Comment: Just adding: `<DeterministicSourcePaths>` goes inside a `<PropertyGroup>` tag.